# Recorrer Buttons en un Grid Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de recorrer todos los Buttons en un Grid con un forech para que todos hagan una funcion ya creada y no tenga que escribirlo button por button.

Este seria el XAML

```
 <Grid x:Name="Tablero" ColumnSpacing="-3" RowSpacing="-3" Padding="30">
                    
                    <Button x:Name="A1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="NumClicked" 
                            Style="{StaticResource Key=NumBtn}" Text="A1"/>
                    <Button x:Name="A2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Clicked="NumClicked"
                            Style="{StaticResource Key=NumBtn}" Text="A2"/>
                    <Button x:Name="A3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Clicked="NumClicked"
                            Style="{StaticResource Key=NumBtn}" Text="A3"/>
                    <Button x:Name="A4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Clicked="NumClicked"
                            Style="{StaticResource Key=NumBtn}" Text="A4"/>
                    <Button x:Name="A5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Clicked="NumClicked"
                            Style="{StaticResource Key=NumBtn}" Text="A5"/>

                </Grid>
```

Y esto lo que estoy intentando para recorrerlo,pero me sale un error que dice que hay ambihuedad

```
        foreach (Button item in Tablero)
        {
            // Funcion();
        }
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: creo que seria mejor si en lugar de usar clicked usas un Command y en tu Viewmodel en ese Command mandas a llamar a tu función.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi,dejo la respuesta por si alguien la necesita

```
    foreach (Button item in Tablero.Children)
    {
        // Funcion();
    }
```